# Writing a loop in Excel for Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel

How do i write the following code as a loop. I want to copy values from a table in sheet 4 in a row from range (b:17:L17"). is there a more efficient way to do it with loops ?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G8")

ActiveSheet.Range("C17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G9")

ActiveSheet.Range("D17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G10")

ActiveSheet.Range("E17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G11")
ActiveSheet.Range("F17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G12")
ActiveSheet.Range("G17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G13")
ActiveSheet.Range("H17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G14")

ActiveSheet.Range("I17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G15")

ActiveSheet.Range("J17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G16")


ActiveSheet.Range("K17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G17")

ActiveSheet.Range("L17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G18")
```

Comment: See [flow control structures](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures#t=201612151953105925624) on Documentation.SO.

Comment: How did this question get upvotes?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B17:L17").Value = Application.Transpose(Sheets(4).Range("G8:G18").Value)
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks, but I just realized that the OP wanted a"more efficient way with loops", guess this probably is beyond expectation lol.

Comment: This is more efficient since Excel contains this function, definitely this is the best solution: neat and easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can, using something like this (VB.Net, but may copy easily to VBA):

```
Dim cell as Integer, c as Integer
cell = 8
For c = 66 To 76
   ActiveSheet.Range(Chr(c) & "17").Value = Sheets(4).Range("G" & cell)
   cell = cell + 1
Next
```

The Chr() function gets the character associated with the character code (66-76), and then this value is concatenated with the string "17" to form a complete cell name ("B17", "C17", ...)

I am also incrementing the cell number for G at the same time.

---

Use this if you really want to use a loop - but there could be better ways, like the [answer given by @A.S.H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172174/1620916)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks - too aggressive on the highlighting.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Absolutely right... this could be expanded to include a lot more possible values, but at that point I would recommend using something better any way, like A.S.H's answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution explanation:***

Establish your rules! What is changing in the range for active sheet? The column is going to grow as the for/to cycle does! So, we should sum that to it. What is the another thing that is going to increment? The Range in the other side of the  '=' so, by setting an algorithm, we may say that the row is const in the Activesheet range and the column is the on variable on the other side.

***Solution:***

```
Sub Test()
Const TotalInteractions As Long = 11
Dim CounterInteractions As Long
    For CounterInteractions = 1 To TotalInteractions
    'where 1 is column A so when it starts the cycle would be B,C and so on
    'where 7 is the row to start so when it begins it would became 8,9 and so on for column G
    ActiveSheet.Cells(17, 1 + CounterInteractions).Value = Sheets(4).Cells(7 + CounterInteractions, 7)
    Next CounterInteractions
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your most efficient solution in a with statement:

```
Sub LoopExample()
  Sheets("Sheet4").Range("G8:G18").Copy
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: That will copy more than just `.Value`s.  It also copies to the wrong sheet (should be `Sheets(4)`) and it also copies to cells G8:Q8 rather than to G8:G18.  And the source and destination are the wrong way around.

Comment: @YowE3K You are impressive! :D

Comment: It's not going to work without a transpose at a minimum, so probably you want to do a copy followed a pastespecial values transpose.

Comment: (a) `Sheets("Sheet2")` should be `ActiveSheet`. (I assume "Sheet2" was where you were testing.)  (b) There is no point in having a `With` block if you are only using each object once.  (c) The downside of using the clipboard to do a Copy/Paste is that some other application (or the user) may use the clipboard between when the `Copy` occurs and the `Paste` occurs, thus corrupting your data.  That's one of the reasons why I believe A.S.H's solution is better - it bypasses the clipboard.